# Применить js к результату выполнения php

Tags: javascript, php, кэширование

Объясните, пожалуйста:

На страницах сайта (.php) публикуются табличные данные, получаемые из БД php-скриптом. Каждому url сайта соответствует один конкретный запрос к БД.

Ради снижения нагрузки на хостинг, **всем пользователям, кроме первого, отдается страница.html из кэша**. Результат запроса к БД сохраняется в кэше при первом посещении конкретного url-а и хранится до следующего обновления БД.

Проблема в том, что данных много. И они плохо воспринимаются целиком в таком количестве.

Поэтому я хочу применить к этим страницам js, чтобы данные, получаемые из БД, отображались не сразу полностью, а частями.

И вот тут **я не понимаю, к чему мне нужно применить js.**

К результату работы php-скрипта, получающего данные из БД? Предварительно положив этот результат в переменную?

Или к конечному html (массив строк таблицы tr), который отдается юзеру из кэша?
Как в этом случае быть с первым посетителем, получающим данные из БД?

Буду очень благодарна за разъяснение, как поступают в таких "навороченных" случаях.

Comment: таблицы? советую попробовать: https://datatables.net

Comment: Как много у вас строк в таблице на каждой странице?

Comment: 200 строк. LIMIT указан 200

Answer (score 0):

Случай вовсе не навороченный) решений много.
Работу с большими данными я бы оставлял серверу, вы же не знаете с какого компьютера сидит ваш конечный пользователь. Есть опасность, что большой объем данных приведет к зависанию браузера пользователя.

1) Самое простое решение реализовать [пагинацию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)

2) Ещё можно реализовать подгрузку страницы с помощью AJAX

3) Если уже делать всё на стороне клиента, то можно часть таблицы скрыть с помощью CSS `display:none`, а при скроле или по требованию пользователя отображать части таблицы.